2 round trip tickets
My son is flying to Venice on a round trip ticket. He will be in Italy for 3 months.
I want to fly to Venice for his last week there and fly back together.
Can this be booked so we are on the same flight home?

I’m not sure I understand the difficulty? You select the dates and flights when you book… While making sure you sit together may be more difficult (depending on the airline, fare, etc.), being on the same flight(s) is just a matter of… selecting the same flight(s)… (as long as there is availability of course)

What makes you think it might not be possible? Which airline(s)?


Can this be booked so we are on the same flight home?

Sure. You just need to book two separate round trip tickets that have the same return flight.
It's best to book both of the tickets at the same time (more or less) so you can be sure the flights are availability, you have full visibility of the total price and can select seats together.
You cannot "link" the booking, so when changes happen (by you or by the airline) you need to manually keep them in sync. This can all be done, but might get expensive (depending on what exactly happens).

It should be possible with different methods:

Check cancellation policies (if you have some hours to cancel). Maybe with a small fee.

do it in parallel, two computers: you may have some time before confirmation.

travel agency (if you can find one)

contact airline


In short: websites often doesn't allow quick cancellation of flights, but other tools allow it (within a certain period): it is necessary for travel agents (and airlines) for complex routes (not just your example, but also routes with different airlines, or to prepare an offer to client before definitive booking.
But also note: usually it means you need to pay more (service or just not the cheapest flights).
